# Download an image through url using perl

Tags: image, perl, download

I have few links of the images which i am trying download it by the use of LWP::Simple;

The code i use for download images is

`getstore($imglink, $name);`

the image  [link](http://cdn.chv.me/images/thumbnails/7_Inch_Android_4_0_Tablet_zzMn_tSh.jpg.thumb_70x70.jpg)

the link is works ,the images is visible if i see the link through my browser.but i am not able to download it.

i have tried this also

`open (FH,">$img_name");

                    binmode (FH);
                    print FH $image_content;
                    #close (FH);`

but i am failing to download the images , Please give me some guidance.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added proper useragent and cookies. try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $lwp = LWP::UserAgent->new(agent=>' Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0', cookie_jar=>{});

my $link = 'http://cdn.chv.me/images/thumbnails/7_Inch_Android_4_0_Tablet_zzMn_tSh.jpg.thumb_70x70.jpg';

my $resp = $lwp->mirror($link, '/tmp/i.jpg');

unless($resp->is_success) {
    print $resp->status_line;
}
```